# Different index return value types for similar conditionals in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to solve some questions in pandas and I had two different functions:

One was coded with the return value as

```
return df.index[df['Gold']==df['Gold'].max()]
```

This was to return which index value had the highest value of gold

Other one:

```
return df.index[(df['Gold']-df['Gold.1']).min()]
```

This is used to represent the index with maximum difference of gold and gold1

When I return values, they are represented differently.

For the first code my return value is:

```
Index(['United States'], dtype='object')
```

For the second one:

```
'Montenegro'
```

What am I doing differently here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas already provides a method for that, [`idxmin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) and [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'gold':[1,2,3,6,3,4,7], 'gold.1':[2,6,3,4,6,2,2]})

>>> df

   gold  gold.1
0     1       2
1     2       6
2     3       3
3     6       4
4     3       6
5     4       2
6     7       2

>>> df.gold.idxmax()
6

>>> (df['gold'] - df['gold.1']).idxmin() 
1

# though you probably need 
# >>> abs(df.gold - df['gold.1']).idxmin()
# 2
```

BTW, in your approaches, one is logical indexing other is general indexing, for my example dataframe it would look like:

```
>>> df['gold']==df['gold'].max()

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
Name: gold, dtype: bool

>>> (df['gold']-df['gold.1']).min()
-4
```

The second one does not do what you intend. It simply finds the minimum difference between `gold` and `gold.1`, which is -4 in this case, and finds that index from `df.index` so it is essentially:

```
>>> df.index[-4]  # i.e. fourth from the end
3
```

However, you would see that the minimum difference occurs at index `-1`, not `3`:

```
>>> df['gold']-df['gold.1']

0   -1
1   -4
2    0
3    2
4   -3
5    2
6    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it clears up a lot of doubts. What method would I use for Series, if I have to get index of series with a particular condition ?

Comment: Use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: What would I use to get index of the series where the condition becomes true, any example works with np.where ?